# Apple in-app subscription : how to detect if the subscription is auto renewing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Here is my response to fetch my latest receipt. I apply subscription which is monthly. That implies a flag to tell us that the monthly subscription auto renews its expires_date . Would you please tell me which param tells auto renewing subscription is enabled ?

```
 "latest_receipt_info" =         (
                    {
            "expires_date" = "2019-07-31 13:08:33 Etc/GMT",
            "expires_date_ms" = 1564578513000,
            "expires_date_pst" = "2019-07-31 06:08:33 America/Los_Angeles",
            "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false,
            "is_trial_period" = false,
            "original_purchase_date" = "2019-07-31 12:09:11 Etc/GMT",
            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1564574951000,
            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2019-07-31 05:09:11 America/Los_Angeles",
            "original_transaction_id" = 1000000552773665,
            "product_id" = "MP20190527_2",
            "purchase_date" = "2019-07-31 13:03:33 Etc/GMT",
            "purchase_date_ms" = 1564578213000,
            "purchase_date_pst" = "2019-07-31 06:03:33 America/Los_Angeles",
            quantity = 1,
            "transaction_id" = 1000000552793408,
            "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000045982930,
        }
    ),




   "pending_renewal_info" =         (
                        {
                "auto_renew_product_id" = "MP20190527_2",
                "auto_renew_status" = 1,
                "original_transaction_id" = 1000000552773665,
                "product_id" = "MP20190527_2",
            }
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per apple doc if user turned off auto renew, value of auto_renew_status flag will be 0.

Please refer following apple doc for receipt field with description for more information

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW8

[image]

Comment: That means if user cancels the subscription , the flag turns 0?

Comment: Do we need to use expiration_intent to detect if the user cancels its subscription or not ?

Comment: That means if user cancels the subscription , the flag turns 0? 
--> Yes

Comment: Do we need to use expiration_intent to detect if the user cancels its subscription or not ?
--> To detect user cancel manually or not we can use this flag. Here is some description from apple. for that field
“1” - Customer canceled their subscription.
“2” - Billing error; for example customer’s payment information was no longer valid.
“3” - Customer did not agree to a recent price increase.
“4” - Product was not available for purchase at the time of renewal.
“5” - Unknown error.

This key is only present for a receipt containing an expired auto-renewable subscription.